# Oracle Function to Parse XML Type

Tags: xml, oracle

I've got one of the fields of a table returning data as follows:

```
<row id="12345">
<car>BMWX1-546</car>
<car>BMWX2-765</car>
</row>
```

I want to create a function that would help me loop through and search according to the Vehicle Model so that I can obtain the Registration No.

I've started the following, but when I compile I get ORA-00936 error.

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_REG_NO(veh_model VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

    MODELS_REGNOS XMLTYPE;
    REG_NO VARCHAR2(100);
    v_count NUMBER(38) := 1;
    BEGIN

        SELECT
        XMLRECORD
        INTO MODELS_REGNOS
        FROM 
        VEHICLES;

        WHILE MODELS_REGNOS.existsNode('//row/car[' || v_count || ']') = 1 LOOP
        REG_NO := MODELS_REGNOS.extract('//row/car[' || v_count || ']/text()').getStringVal();
        v_count := v_count + 1;
        END LOOP;

      RETURN REG_NO ;

    END GET_REG_NO;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete text of the error messages. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a tiny typo. The query is failing because you don't have an alias `a` for the table.

```
SELECT
a.XMLRECORD
INTO MODELS_REGNOS
FROM 
VEHICLES a;
```

Comment: I should've removed the "a" in my code sample above actually. I added the alias and got the same error.

Comment: Really? Because just copy/pasting your code and adding the "a" works for me. `select GET_REG_NO(null) from dual;` returns `BMWX2-765`